# Calculating the amount of energy lost

Tags: forces, potential-energy

I am trying to finish up an problem dealing with loss of energy. It is a mini-lab where you take out a bouncy ball and drop it from an already recorded height and then also collect how high it bounces. The mass is already known. The main question is to then "Calculate the amount of energy lost in bounce and to air resistance. What formula should be used in this situation? I understand the base of KE = PE but since velocity isn't included I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Hint: you start out with a certain amount of gravitational potential energy, and after one bounce, the ball does not get to its original height.

Comment: Additional hint: There are points in your trajectory where the speed is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the velocity at all. Start from conservation of energy.Let the initial condition be when you drop the ball and the final condition is when the ball has bounced back up (and its velocity is zero).

$E_{init} = E_{final}$

$U_{init} + K_{init} = U_{final} + K_{final} + E_{lost}$

The kinetic energies at the points that we are considering is zero so

$U_{init}  = U_{final} + E_{lost}$

Now you can calculate $E_{lost}$ from the above equation